# Need something like StructureFrame that includes listings as well as pages

Tags: structure

Does anyone know of a way/existing fieldtype out there there that does exactly what StructureFrame does, but includes listings?

StructureFrame is a really neat way to link to content, but annoying that you can't access all of it!

Comment: You're describing functionality like the link options in Wygwam, right? Where you can choose a listing channel to get a link from in addition to choosing pages?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use Playa or the native field type connected to whatever the listing channel is.

Comment: Playa isn't ideal when I want to give the option of linking to any page/listing across the entire site. A drop down like StructureFrame where it's all in the same order as the Structure tree would be ideal (even if, in some cases, a bit long!) - also, Playa is a $70 add on.